# How to delete row after 10 minutes?

Tags: mysql

I have an application which simulate ticket reservation in cinema. And when client choose seat it blocks it in mysql database which means that it inserts row to table reservations with clientFK = null. And i would like to delete that row after 10 minutes. I tried crate event:

```
CREATE EVENT delete_tmp_res
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 minute
DO
DELETE FROM cinema.reservation Where clientFK is NULL;
```

but it doesn't work at all. What should i do?

Comment: Are you sure the event scheduler is running? Does `SHOW PROCESSLIST` show a row with user = `event_scheduler`?

Comment: Beware that, once you get this working, MySQL will delete unfinished reservations every ten minutes—no matter how long it has been since those reservations began.  So, I might only just have commenced a booking when the 10-minute timer elapses and my booking is purged.  Better to store the time that a booking commenced and periodically purge those that have expired.

Comment: @Barmar no, it was off, thanks.

Comment: Also, shouldn't removing of reserved tickets be paused while there is still a valid session for the user? First because it is unintuitive or unexpected if the user is still interacting with the site, but his reservation is silenty deleted (I would think: that site is really broken...), second it will save you hassle, since you do not have to handle that case of a silently deleted reservation inside a valid and ongoing session.

Comment: @eggyal i think that 10 minutes is more than enough

Comment: @pawkondr Your last comment suggests you did not bother to understand what has been tried to point out.

Comment: @arkascha after 10 minutes program will check again if that seats are free to take and if so it will add row with clientFK, if don't it will tell user that he must choose seats again

Comment: @pawkondr: you miss my point, which is that as currently styled it's only a *maximum* of 10 minutes that for each user could be *any time up to* that limit.  In the example I gave, my reservation was purged near immediately.

Comment: I have the impression this site still needs some thoughts to be spent on UX :-)

Comment: I will think about your conserns. Is it even possible to create event like that without timestamp as a column in table?

Comment: I already outlined the correct solution in my first comment.  What's the problem with having a timestamp column?

Comment: @pawkondr To explain it another way, the event runs at 12:00, 12:10, 12:20, etc. If a user creates a reservation at 12:09, it will be deleted when the event runs at 12:10.

Comment: I will add timestamp. What is correct solution then? CREATE EVENT delete_tmp_res
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 minute
DO
DELETE FROM cinema.reservation Where clientFK is NULL AND now() - timestamp > 10 minutes; something like this?